# Life Cycle of Daemon thread and Non Daemon Thread in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, multithreading, daemon

I'm trying to execute a long-running process (sending mail to around 600 people) using threading module. My Django view and email processing function goes like this:

```
def daily_wap(request):
    context = {
    
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
    
        file = request.FILES.get('dailywap', None)
    
        if file:
            try:
            
                wap = pd.read_excel(file, header = [0,1], engine='openpyxl').dropna(how = 'all')
                t = threading.Thread(target= daily_wap_automailer, kwargs={'wap': wap}, daemon = True)
                t.start()
                messages.success(request , "Task Scheduled")   
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usermanagement:daily_wap_automailer'))
            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(request, 'Error occured: {0}'.format(e))
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usermanagement:daily_wap_automailer'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'File not provided')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usermanagement:daily_wap_automailer'))
    
    return render(request, "wap_automailer.html", context)



def daily_wap_automailer(wap):
    ### In send_mail, im iterating over each mail ids and sending the mail, 
    ### which then returns total mail successfully sent(count) and total no users (total)
    count , total = send_mail(wap=wap)
    return (count , total)
```

I'm executing the function `daily_wap_automailer` using the daemon thread. As per the online  documenation and resources, daemon thread gets terminated as soon as the main/parent thread gets terminated provided it does not have any non-daemon thread to execute.

The main thread (HTTP request response cycle) typically takes less than a sec to complete(sending the message "Task Scheduled" to Client), does it mean that the daemon thread which executes func `daily_wap_automailer` won't have sufficient time to complete the execution (typically takes 10 min)? Will it get abruptly terminated even if its execution is not completed? what if I implement this using a non-daemon thread?

Comment: Depends on the WSGI server and its configuration. In general don't try to run threads in WSGI apps. Use a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) or a task queue (e.g. celery).

Comment: why ? what would happen if threads are executed in wsgi apps? can you please be specific regarding wsgi configurations?

Comment: The WSGI server usually spawns and manages processes and threads. It is very possible that it recycles a process or threads after a request is finished, killing all of the child threads.